# How to prevent phone lock if app is running in background

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using `react-native-background-timer` for running task in background . This library have one issue if user phone get locked then background service is not working . I have decided to prevent phone lock if user using my app or app is running in background .  I am using `expo-keep-awake` for awake a phone to prevent phone lock .  This library working fine if app is foreground if user minimize an app my screen get locked . What I want , if user minimize an app then I want to prevent user screen get locked . I tried hard but didn't find any solution could someone please help me to resolve this issue .

**Background Service Function**

```
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';
import { useKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';

    BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(async () => {
    
      console.log('@@@@@ API has been hit')
    },
      60000);


function ActiveDeliveriesScreen({ navigation }) {

  useKeepAwake();

......

}
```

Comment: Be aware that keeping the phone awake will seriously drain the battery. Most users wont' tolerate this and will uninstall your app. I strongly suggest that you find another solution for running background tasks.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I know that but we have requirement . Could you please help me ?

Comment: Please review [Android's Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) or explain why the timer can't be a foreground service.

Comment: @MorrisonChang is it possible to use it in react native ?

Comment: React Native sits on top of the Java/Kotlin native framework. If you can't find a plugin/module you'll have to write the Java/Kotlin component yourself. Regardless the mobile platform dictates what limits exist on apps no matter the language.

Comment: Yes, I know but I am not android developer . Could you please help me in out ?